# Rails Devise reset_authentication_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Rails 3.2.2 and Devise 2.0.4 with token_authenticatable turned on and everything work well. Now I want to do the following

> When a user logs in or logs out reset_authentication_token for the users

For this I need to override the SessionsController but I dont know where to put the call to reset_authentication_token

(Note I want this only when a user is successfully logged in or out)

Answer (score 2):

You can override the sign_in helper of Devise in ApplicationController:

```
def sign_in(resource_or_scope, *args)
  super
  current_user.reset_authentication_token!
end
```